# Same colour palettes for two different maps in ggplot2

Tags: r, legend, color, ggplot2

I am constructing two ion concentration maps in the UK using `ggplot2`. The dataset used for mapping are `lzn.kriged1` and `lzn.kriged2` which basically has the same structure:

```
> str(lzn.kriged1)
Formal class 'SpatialPointsDataFrame' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
  ..@ data       :'data.frame': 9962 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ var1.pred: num [1:9962] 9.63 10.47 10.39 10.29 10.56 ...
  .. ..$ var1.var : num [1:9962] 10.59 2.16 2.1 2.11 4.79 ...
  ..@ coords.nrs : int [1:2] 1 2
  ..@ coords     : num [1:9962, 1:2] -6.35 -5.25 -5.19 -5.13 -5.72 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:9962] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "x1" "x2"
  ..@ bbox       : num [1:2, 1:2] -8.1 49.95 1.73 60.82
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "x1" "x2"
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "min" "max"
  ..@ proj4string:Formal class 'CRS' [package "sp"] with 1 slot
  .. .. ..@ projargs: chr NA
```

I change the fill colour based on `var1.pred` with the following condition:

```
below 10 = color1
>10-20   = color2
>20-30   = color3
above 30 = color4
```

I use `cut` function to apply that condition:

```
lzn.kriged1 %>% as.data.frame %>% #lzn.kriged2 for MAP2
  ggplot(aes(x=x1, y=x2)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill=cut(var1.pred,breaks=c(0,10,20,30,Inf),
            labels = c("Below 10", ">10-20", ">20-30", "Above 30")))) +
  coord_map() + theme(legend.title=element_blank())
```

which resulted in these maps:

[image]

In MAP 2, the maximum value of `var1.pred` is 19. That is why the legend only shows two levels.

My questions are:

1) How can I control the fill color for each level? For example:

```
below 10 = blue
>10-20   = green
>20-30   = yelow
above 30 = red
```

2) How can I make those two maps to have the same colors and the same legend?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking one question per Question. Please choose the question which is most pressing, [Edit] this to focus on that (being sure to always list the exact software in use), and wait for editing and suggestions on how to improve your question before asking the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `scale_fill_manual()` defining `values()` to maintain color scheme and `limits()` to maintain unused levels:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(raster)
library(dplyr)
library(sp)
library(gridExtra)

data("meuse.grid")

plot1 <- meuse.grid %>% .[!is.na(.$dist),] %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill=cut(dist,breaks=c(-Inf,0.25,0.5,0.75,1),
                         labels = c("Below 10", ">10-20", ">20-30", "Above 30")))) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Below 10" = 'red', ">10-20" = 'blue',
                               ">20-30" = 'green', "Above 30" = 'yellow'),
                    limits = c("Below 10", ">10-20", ">20-30", "Above 30")) +
  coord_equal() + theme(legend.title=element_blank())

plot2 <- meuse.grid %>% .[!is.na(.$dist),] %>%
  mutate(dist = dist/2) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill=cut(dist,breaks=c(-Inf,0.25,0.5,0.75,1),
                         labels = c("Below 10", ">10-20", ">20-30", "Above 30")))) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Below 10" = 'red', ">10-20" = 'blue',
                               ">20-30" = 'green', "Above 30" = 'yellow'),
                    limits = c("Below 10", ">10-20", ">20-30", "Above 30")) +
  coord_equal() + theme(legend.title=element_blank())

grid.arrange(plot1,plot2,ncol=2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is: combine your two datasets in a long-formatted data frame so that MAP1 and MAP2 become a factor variable, and then use facet_wrap to plot them together. Here's an example using a small lump of [raster data](https://github.com/obrl-soil/dsmartr/blob/master/data/heronvale_covariates.rda):

```
library(raster)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

load('C:/data/heronvale_covariates.rda')

# grabbing two layers with similar data range, just for looks
k <- heronvale_covariates[[9]]
u <- heronvale_covariates[[11]]

# casting the data to an SPDF point object like yours first, for demo purposes
k_sp <- as(k, 'SpatialPointsDataFrame')
u_sp <- as(u, 'SpatialPointsDataFrame')

# turn each SPDF into a data frame
k_df <- as.data.frame(k_sp)
u_df <- as.data.frame(u_sp)

# combine
all_df <- dplyr::left_join(k_df, u_df, by = c('x', 'y'))
```

At this point, because of the structure of your SPDFs, you'll have a data frame with columns named `c('x', 'y', 'var1.pred.x', 'var1.var.x', 'var1.pred.y', 'var1.var.y')`. If you only want to plot the two prediction maps, drop the variance data before proceeding.

```
# long-format it so that layer becomes a factor
all_df_long <- tidyr::gather(all_df, 'layer', 'value', -x, -y)
all_df_long$layer <- factor(all_df_long$layer, 
                            labels = c('Potassium', 'Uranium'))
# factorise values (cleaner to do it outside the plot call)
all_df_long$cat <- base::cut(na.omit(all_df_long$value), 
                             breaks = c(0, unlist(quantile(all_df_long$value, 
                                                         c(0.33, 0.66), 
                                                         na.rm =TRUE)), Inf), 
                             labels = c('super low', 'low', 'less low'),
                             include.lowest = TRUE)

# plot
ggplot() +
  geom_raster(data = na.omit(all_df_long), aes(x = x, y = y, fill = cat)) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d() + 
  facet_wrap(. ~ layer, ncol = 2) +
  theme_minimal() +
  # I'm just being fussy from this point on >.>
  labs(fill = 'Level') +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = pretty(all_df_long$x, n = 3)) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), 
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 30),
        axis.ticks.x = element_line()) +
  coord_sf(crs = 3577, datum = 3577)
```

[image]